# guitar chords in songbook after the line

Tags: music, songs, songbook

I am writing songbook and would like to add guitar chords. I consider them secondary to actual lyric and woludn't like them to interfere with normal reading nor take a lot of vertical space.

I use [songs package](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) and know that it can show chords above words. I want to have chords **after** each line, adjusted to left.

[This website](http://www.cdur.pl/Piosenki/765,Przybiezeli_do_Betlejem_pasterze) can show both versions. By default it shows chords as songs package does, but if you click "Zmień styl" at the top it shows how I want it.

How to achieve this effect in latex?

Example file using songs package

```
\documentclass[a5paper, portrait, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[chorded, onesongcolumn]{songs}

\noversenumbers

\begin{document}

\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\beginverse
% pretend there is second verse; chords are the same, so don't repeat them
Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow;
Praise Him, all creatures here below;
Praise Him above, ye heav'nly host;
Praise Father, Son, and Holy Ghost.
Amen.
\endverse
\endsong
% second song
\beginsong{Second song}[]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image]

Comment: There are a number of ways to to do this, the simplest being to use a tabular.  OTOH, I'm not familiar with the songs package or why you are using it.  Perhaps a Minimal Working Example with the chords on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [my answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438974/28900).  I think this solution will also work for you, but you will have to configure your line spacing carefully to avoid overlaps in the marginal notes if you put full-sized tablatures there.

```
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

% Create lengths for the width of the chord area and its left margin
\newlength\chordswidth\setlength\chordswidth{1in}
\newlength\chordsmargin\setlength\chordsmargin{3pt}

\newbox\chbox
\newcommand\clist[1]{\ifchorded
  \ifvmode\leavevmode\fi
  \setbox\chbox\vtop{\raggedright
    \leftskip=\hsize\advance\leftskip-\chordswidth\advance\leftskip\chordsmargin
    \printchord{\transposehere{#1}}\par
  }\vadjust{\vbox{\kern-2pt\kern-\ht\chbox\box\chbox}}\fi\ignorespaces}

\let\oldjustifyleft=\justifyleft
\renewcommand\justifyleft{\oldjustifyleft
  \ifchorded\advance\rightskip\chordswidth\fi}

%no need to have wide spacing between lines if chords above never used:
\newcommand\pausechords{}
\newcommand\resumechords{}
\ifchorded
  \renewcommand\pausechords{\setlength\baselineadj{0pt}\chordsoff}
  \renewcommand\resumechords{\setlength\baselineadj{-10pt}\chordson}
\fi

\begin{document}

\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Doxology}
\beginverse
\clist{G Em G} Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow;
\clist{G Em D} Praise Him, all creatures here below;
\clist{Em D C Em} Praise Him above, ye heav'nly host;
\clist{G D G} Praise Father, Son, and Holy Ghost.
\clist{C G} Amen.
\endverse

\pausechords % second verse without chords
\beginverse
Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow;
Praise Him, all creatures here below;
Praise Him above, ye heav'nly host;
Praise Father, Son, and Holy Ghost.
Amen.
\endverse
\resumechords
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need, however there is problem with first line: https://ibb.co/cxUQZy - do you know how to fix it? I use songs 2.18

Comment: I fixed it; please try the new code.  (My original didn't account for numbered verses.)

Comment: This is great solution, thank you! Any chance of improving it further so that verses between \chordsoff \chordson don't have superfluous margin?

Comment: That's pretty easy to do.  Just surround the part that advances \rightskip by \chordswidth with \ifchorded...\fi.  I've done so.